# jQuery UI Accordion - content from previous section loading on click of different section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement the sortable jQuery UI accordion but when I click on section one for example it opens with no content, if I then click section two the content from section one tries to load but the section is closed before it fully loads and section two opens with no content.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <title>History of Le Mans</title>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/common.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="JS/common.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul id="tabs">
        <li><a href="#" id="tab1" name="#tabContent1" class="activeTab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="tab2" name="#tabContent2">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="tab3" name="#tabContent3">The Circuit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="tab4" name="#tabContent4">Gallery</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#" id="tab5" name="#tabContent5">Further Reading</a></li>    
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="tabContent1"></div>
      <div id="tabContent2">
        <div id="accordion">
          <div class="group">
            <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <div>
              <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="group">
            <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <div>
              <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="group">
            <h3>Section 3</h3>
            <div>
              <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
              <ul>
                <li>List item one</li>
                <li>List item two</li>
                <li>List item three</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="group">
            <h3>Section 4</h3>
            <div>
              <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est. </p><p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="tabContent3"></div>
      <div id="tabContent4"></div>
      <div id="tabContent5"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
  $(function () {
    $("#accordion")
      .accordion({
        header: "> div > h3"
      })
      .sortable({
        axis: "y",
        handle: "h3",
        stop: function (event, ui) {
          ui.item.children("h3").triggerHandler("focusout");
        }
      });
  });
```

jQuery tutorial: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#sortable

What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the accordion being rendered while not visible. You can see an issue [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3905), it is listed as won't fix.

Your options are to either create the accordion with the option `{ heightStyle: "content" }`, or call `$("#accordion").accordion("refresh");`  once the tab has been navigated to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" )
        .accordion({
            header: "> div > h3",
            heightStyle: "content"
        })
        .sortable({
            axis: "y",
            handle: "h3",
            stop: function( event, ui ) {
                // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
                // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
                ui.item.children( "h3" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );
            }
        });
});
```